# Apache CXF web service doesn't return string array

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am new in java web service programming and this question might seem really basic. But I can't find the problem.

I have developed a Apache CXF(v 2.7.6) webservice for Tomcat 6.0.37 using Eclipse.
Basically, I created a dynamic web project, created webservice class and created webservice from that class (eclipse generated the rest, including wsdl and xsd). All works fine, except when I try to return array of String. 
This is my method

```
@WebMethod(action="getFriends")
    public String[] getFriends(String u, String p){
        return new String[] {"item 1","item 2","item 3"};
    }
```

response type definition

```
<xs:complexType name="getFriendsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

and here is the returned message

### INFO: Outbound Message

ID: 34
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload:

As you can see there is no even return part. Any idea what can be wrong?

I use Windows 7, Eclipse Kepler and JDK6 for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever I remember it won't work because you can't parse an array as plain text in a HTTP response.

Try these two approaches -
1 ) Change the return type of your method to String and then return a string like this

```
 return Arrays.toString(new String[] {"item 1","item 2","item 3"});
```

2 ) You can change the return type of list and return a list like this -

```
return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"item 1","item 2","item 3"});
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I also thought about converting the array to string, then on the client side converting to to array again.

But it's strange that on complex types Eclipse shows error when generating the webservice. But for String[] it generated without any errors. 

For now I will go with this solution, thanks.

Comment: what error you are talking about "Eclipse shows error when generating the webservice" ?
And if above answers your query  , then please mark it as answered so that it can help other visitors having same problem. - Thanks